# Plot using only the rows in which another column matches a particular value [Excel]

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Say I have data like

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
TeamA  Total  10
TeamA  P1     5
TeamA  P3     3
TeamB  Total  12
TeamB  P1     5
TeamB  P2     4
etc
```

And want to plot the values of `Col3` only if `Col2 = Total`. This is a long table, so manually selecting the correct rows is not ideal. The positioning of the rows that contain `Total` will also change depending on the data, so it should be able to be automatically determined rather than relying on a particular row number.

This is something fairly straightforward in R or Python, but doesn't seem to be the case in Excel. I've considered having another column that returns the row number of `Col2` for all cases matching the string `"Total"`, then using this as input into the plot data-series somehow. I haven't been able to get that to work, and also wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: This is very easy with pivot chart, there you can add filter.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I don't have ready access to Excel, but will just filtering work?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Good point, thanks. This works well for 1D data like my example. Do you have any suggestions for 2D data or 3D data? It appears that Pivot Charts can't do these.

Comment: @conor: you can filter it on a pivot table,  then copy data to a new location and create chart from there. I don't know easier way.

Comment: @fixer1234 filter pivot, not the source data.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I'm missing the point of the pivot table.  Maybe I've misunderstood the question.  I posted an answer with where I was headed with my comment question.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pivot table and filter your data there.

For majority of charts you can also create a pivot chart from pivot table to get what you need.

For some chart types however (e.g. scatter plot) can't be created from pivot table, this case workaround is to copy data from pivot table to a new location and create the chart based on that new one.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but it seems like this can be done just by filtering the data.  I'm using LO Calc, rather than Excel, but, I entered the data from the example, turned on filtering, and selected Total in column B.  Then I just selected columns A and C of the displayed data and inserted a chart (no attempt to select any particular options because I don't know what your charting goals are).  This was the result:

[image: sample chart]

After posting this, I got feedback that it doesn't work in Excel.  It's pretty unusual that LO Calc can do something Excel can't.  To test it, I found an old installed version of Excel and replicated it.  Here's the result:

[image: sample in Excel]

Just to prove that I didn't fake it by including just the Total lines, here's the spreadsheet without the filtering:

[image: sample without filtering]

So assuming this is what you're trying to do, it looks like you can just use filtering.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 , yes this can be done in Excel but by doing so you either change the original table or copy a fair bit of it. The pivot chart answer suits my needs better and allows more flexibility and interactivity.

Comment: @conor, great that you have a solution, but I'm not sure why you think you need to change or copy anything to use filtering.  That's done in place and doesn't change the data.  It just hides the rows that don't meet the criteria.  So, for example, your total rows were rows 2 and 5, and if you look at the filtered versions, it's just hiding the other rows.  In the last image, I just deselected the filter and you can see all of the original data.  Filtering is a built-in feature that it layers on top of your data without changing anything.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand that. What I meant is that the data table is presented as a report that the users in this instance want to be able to just glance at as-is and see the full thing. So leaving that table alone, I'd need to copy it to a new place, filter the copy, and create a plot from that. Of course, this is effectively what I'm doing with the pivot tables/plots anyway, so the difference is probably minimal. I should have anticipated the solution before asking it, but was thinking along more programmatic lines, forgetting I was using Excel for a minute!